# In which moment a widget is added to the dijit registry

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm a dojo newbie and i'm receiving

```
TypeError: registry.byId("aDojoView") is undefined
```

when i'm looking for a dojo view using registry.byId()

I put some logs on DOM ready and load, and appear before the error. So the DOM is already parsed by that time.

I tried to look in dijit's documentation but i haven't found how and when the widgets are added to the dijit's registry. 
I wonder if there is some kind of event triggered too

Comment: Found on "Mastering dojo" book : "When Dijit creates a widget,
it places a reference to it in a global registry. Even if the DOM node is
removed and the visual portion of the widget disappears, the global registry entry remains"   I guess i need to investigate now in which moment dijit is creating the widgets

Comment: Printed the content of the registry when i do the registry.byId() and got  "undefined" and the "length" property and it's zero.

Comment: The registry it's never being populated, i need to figure out why

Comment: Write a piece of your code, not just the error

Answer (score 1):

Please look at source code of `_WidgetBase.js` at line 428, [visible here](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_WidgetBase.js).
It looks like that a widget object is being added to `registry` in the `create` function, so after execution of `postMixInProperties` and `postMixInProperties`.

Here below dijit life-cycle:

```
postMixInProperties
buildRendering
-- widget instance added to the registry here
postCreate
create
postscript
startup
```